# customize OrderBy for a List?

Tags: c#, android, linq, listview, collections

I have a list of items and I want to create two ways to sort them, Alphabetically and Last Modified.

Here's what I did:

```
// Alphabetically
tableItems = tableItems.OrderBy (MyTableItem => MyTableItem.ItemName).ToList();
reloadTable(tableItems);

// Last Modified
tableItems = tableItems.OrderBy (MyTableItem => MyTableItem.Timestamp).ToList();
reloadTable(tableItems);
```

and this works perfectly fine.

My problem is I want this happen to all items in the list except for one.
This one item will always be constant and I want to make sure it's ALWAYS on the top of the list.

What would I need to do for that?

if it matters, c# is the lang.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tableItems = tableItems.OrderBy(i => i.ItemName != "yourexceptitem").ThenBy(i => i.Timestamp).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to sort the itemname except one, do like this,

```
 tableItems = tableItems.OrderBy(i => i.ItemName != "TestSubject3").ToList();
```

Comment: I think I didn't ask the right question.  Itemname and timestamp are two completely different sort options.  Let's say I want to sort only by name but all items except for item named "TestSubject3".  How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Other, generic solution:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByExcept<T>(
                this IEnumerable<T> source,
                 Predicate<T> exceptPredicate,
                 Func<IEnumerable<T>, IOrderedEnumerable<T>> projection)
{
    var rest = new List<T>();

    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (exceptPredicate(enumerator.Current))
            {
                yield return enumerator.Current;
            }
            else
            {
                rest.Add(enumerator.Current);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (var elem in projection(rest))
    {
        yield return elem;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
tableItems = tableItems.OrderByExcept(
                         item => item.ItemName == "TestSubject3",
                         items => items.OrderBy(MyTableItem => MyTableItem.ItemName)
                                       .ThenBy(MyTableItem => MyTableItem.TimeStamp))
                       .ToList();
```

Items that meets predicate will always be on the top of list, to the rest of elements projection will be applied.

Comment: This is good to know. For now, other solution works fine but this will be helpful for other conditions.  Thanks